# key for opening doors

Tags: number-theory

You are standing on the middle of a East-West street. A row of closed doors in front of you, and you have a key on hand which can only open one specific door. Compose a strategy so that X/N value is smallest under the worst situation. X is the distance you covered when arriving at the correct door. N is the distance between the door and the original point.

Comment: Compose a strategy for _what_?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is known as the cow-path problem. The answer is an example of an *online algorithm*. The best $X/N$ is known as the *competitive ratio*. The competitive ratio in your case is~$9$ for deterministic algorithms, and $4.6$ for randomized algorithms.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search_problem) for references.

Comment: That Wikipedia article is almost worthless, I'm afraid.

Comment: Google "cow path problem" instead.

Comment: Link to that instead.